# Rational maps from $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I was reading *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* by Silverman,I had the following question:
Is there a way to classify rational maps from $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ over some algebraically closed field K?

Now,rational maps between non-singular varieties of dimension one are morphisms.Then
$\phi:\mathbb{P}^{1}\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{1}$ is a morphism with deg$\phi$=1.Then $\phi$ has to be an isomorphism.Hence,rational maps between $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ and $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ must be isomorphisms.

Is this a correct reasoning or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: $[x:y]\mapsto [x^2:y^2]$ is a rational map that is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @HankScorpio So,it's incorrect to assume deg$\phi$=1 right?Also,is there any nice way to classify all such maps?

Comment: Yes. In general, a map $\Bbb P^1\to\Bbb P^1$ is given by two coprime homogeneous polynomials of the same degree.

Comment: @ronno ok, done.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $\phi$ must be an isomorphism, nor that $\deg\phi$ must be 1. For instance, $[x:y]\to [x^2:y^2]$ is a map which is of degree 2 and is not an isomorphism.

In general, a map $\Bbb P^1\to \Bbb P^1$ is given by a two coprime homogeneous polynomials of the same degree.

Comment: And the common degree of the polynomials is the degree of $\phi$ as a map.